# Format a string with a decimal separator between every 3 digits

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MySQL database, I have a string like `123456789`. I want to add a decimal separator between every 3 digits, and thus turn it into `123.456.789`.

How can I do this?

Comment: the best solution would be to do this with the software language you use when it retrieves data from sql. For example : https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.number-format.php

Comment: It's unclear if what you want is to change the format of the output of a `SELECT` query, or if you want to actually modify data on the DB.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL **8.0+**, it is possible to use the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(YOUR_COLUMN, '([:digit:]{3})(?!$)', '$0.');
```

It adds a dot for each group of 3 digits, excepted for the last one.
Here are some examples:

> `123456789` returns `123.456.789`
>
> `1234567891` returns `123.456.789.1`
>
> `12345678910` returns `123.456.789.12`

You can try it out on this [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m45NGRirW8HFqBev7WYQ2J/0) and you can change the regular expression to fit what you need.

However, this approach is probably not the best in terms of performance. If your query is called a lot of times, your database server will suffer since calculation is centralized on it. As @xNoJustice said, it is better to handle this string operation in the client part, where it will be divided between every client execution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function with suitable locale.

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vgyhu28TMxTGrQ2KJeMjnk/0), which shows all suitable locales.